# DbLookup Keywords

Tags: xpages

is there a list available with the possible keywords for the keyword parameter in the @DbLookup statement?

is there also an explanation available for those keywords?

Thanks
Mario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for the help topic for @DbLookup in the Lotus Domino Designer Help database which is part of your Notes client installation (and part of the Domino server installation). The following is taken from that documentation about the Keyword parameter:

```
Keyword. Optional. Keywords can be concatenated.
[FAILSILENT] returns "" (null string) instead of an error if the key cannot be found.
[PARTIALMATCH] returns a match if the key matches the beginning characters of the column value.
[RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID] returns the UNID of the document instead of a field or column value.
```

You can also find the documentation online at the Information Center:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DBLOOKUP_NOTES_DATABASES.html

Comment: Just be aware that the @DbLookup method expects text, so you need "[FAILSILENT]", not [FAILSILENT]